# Solve recurrence with Master Theorem - Polynomially Smaller/Larger

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, master-theorem

The problem is to solve the recurrence using Master Theorem :

$$T(n) = 2T(n/2)+\log_2 {n}$$

**My attempt:**
$$ a=2, b=2, f(n)= \log_2 {n}, g(n)=n^{\log_b{a}}=n $$ I am torn between case 1 & the Master Theorem not applying. 
I notice that $\log_2{n}$ cannot be written as a polynomial, but the ratio of $f/g = \log_2{n}/n$, which has an $n$ term in it. And $f$ clearly is less than $g$. So, does case 1 apply or not? I have found very mixed results online, and, ultimately, I am unclear of if in this case it is considered polynomially smaller and what that constitutes in general. (see definition on this from book below)

The version of the Master Theorem we use is as follows:
[image: Master Theorem]

Our book also notes that in the first case not only must $f$ be smaller than $n^{\log_b{a}}$, it must *polynomially smaller*, that is, $f$ must be asymptotically smaller than $n^{\log_b{a}}$ by a factor of $n^\varepsilon$ for some constant $\varepsilon>0$. Similarly, in the third case, not only must $f$ be larger than $n^{\log_b{a}}$, it must *polynomially larger*.

Comment: This looks like your second homework question in very short time. Could you tell us the name of your instructor, in case he or she wants to post some help here?

Comment: You talk about the ratio $f/g$, but I don't see any $g$ here, so I'm not sure what that refers to.  The statement of case 1 tells you under what condition it applies.  have you figured out what $a$ and $b$ are and whether $f(n) = O(n^{\log_b a-\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$?  If not, what progress did you make on that?

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed to clarify what I meant by $g, a, b$, so $n^{\log_b{a}}=n$. I am confused on if I can say $f=\log_2{n}$ is polynomially smaller than $n$. That definition is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the definition.  Does there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(n) = O(n^{1-\epsilon})$?  If yes, then case 1 applies (just see the text that you included in the question).  If no, then case 1 does not apply.

For instance, ask yourself: if $\epsilon=0.1$, does $f(n)=O(n^{1-\epsilon})$?  i.e., does $\log n=O(n^9)$?   You should be able to take it from here.